Does the superuser in grub.cfg have to be real?
Kind of an odd one here - I'm following these instructions to password protect my GRUB menu. Part of the process is adding the below to /etc/grub.d/40_custom, which is later added to grub.cfg:
set superusers="root"
password_pbkdf2 root grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.<insert hash here>

Afterwards, I run sudo update-grub.
I'm trying to debug why GRUB doesn't ask for a user and password when I boot. To that end, is the superuser mentioned in set superusers= referencing the user records stored in /etc/passwd and set /etc/shadow, or does GRUB have a separate list of (super)users?
Could I have my grub.cfg include:
set superusers="abcdef"
password_pbkdf2 abcdef grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.<insert hash here>

where abcdef is not a user that exists in /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow, and so abcdef can be used to authenticate into GRUB, but not anywhere else?

After some testing, I found that no, the user doesn't have to be real. User "abcdef" above can log in to get through the GRUB screen, but can't sign into the machine.
